# Configuring Azure network security group

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-virtual-network

I enabled NSG for my SF cluster and now trying to enable 'Streaming Traces' for cluster from visual studio. I keep on receiving this error (availble in Microsoft Azure Activity Log):

*"Configuring network security group 'MyNSG' used by cluster 'MyCluster' - The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.  Microsoft.Cct.StatusWindow.DispatchedStatusItemContainer".*

What do I need to do in order to get rid of this error? Enabling traces was possible before setting up the NSG.

Comment: In my case, Visual Studio fails with error when trying to enable 'Streaming Traces' when NSG enabled. When NSG disabled, it works. Any update on the issue?
The error of cloud explorer is "unable to get property 'split'".

Answer (score 0):

I think status code indicates that the Azure SDN stack cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be an error due to malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing. This what Azure support can assist you with when you reach out for help.